# DEBUG net.jmob.guice.conf.core.internal.virtual.BeanValidator - No validation factory found in classpath

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, guice

in my test project I'm reading my env settings as per instruction in: https://github.com/yyvess/Guice-configuration. Those are only tests written with Java Maven and Cucumber so I dont need Spring or any additional validations as its supposed to be light and clear.

Even though my tests are running I still have same DEBUG info:

> DEBUG net.jmob.guice.conf.core.internal.virtual.BeanValidator - No validation factory found in classpath

How can I tell my class not to look for any validation factory? Im not going to use one at all.

My config (HOCON .conf) sample:

```
username = "myUsername"
password = "myPassword"
```

My GuiceModule:

```
package properties;
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import net.jmob.guice.conf.core.ConfigurationModule;
import java.io.File;

public class GuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        **//after line below comes the bug "No validation factory found in classpath"**
        install(new ConfigurationModule()
                .fromPath(new File("./config")));
        requestInjection(Props.class);
    }
}
```

My Props sample:

```
package properties;

import lombok.Data;
import net.jmob.guice.conf.core.BindConfig;
import net.jmob.guice.conf.core.InjectConfig;

import static net.jmob.guice.conf.core.Syntax.CONF;

@BindConfig(value = "config", syntax = CONF, resolve = true)
@Data
public class Props {
    @InjectConfig("username")
    String username;

    @InjectConfig("password")
    String password;
}
```

Here's how I read my properties in classes needing them:

```
package request_helpers;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import properties.GuiceModule;
import properties.Props;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Value
public class MyClass{
    Props props;

    @Inject
    public MyClass() {
        this.props = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule()).getInstance(Props.class);
    }

    //just an example of method - not real one 
    public String getUsername() {
        return props.getUsername();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can look at the source and see that there is no such possibility.

https://github.com/yyvess/Guice-configuration/blob/master/src/main/java/net/jmob/guice/conf/core/internal/virtual/BeanValidator.java

Comment: Ok, thats disappointing, 'cause at the begining it also says: "Optionally, to active validation, you must import a validator like Hibernate validator".

Is there a quick way to add it to GuiceModule class? I've added jakarta, hibernate.validator and glassfish dependencies + created simple ValidationFactory in constructor but I get even more errors. Tried:

    public GuiceModule() {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validation = validatorFactory.getValidator();
    }

Comment: Nah. The readme uses the wrong term. Adding the dependency should be sufficient. But have a look at the Javadoc for `buildDefaultValidatorFactory` or try to debug what goes on it there. It won't be the last time you'll have to look at `javax.validation` so it's good to poke around a bit.